# Spring boot with GRPC server blocking GRPC client request

Tags: spring-boot, grpc, java-17, grpc-java

I have Spring boot app v.3.2.1 and GRPC server and client in one app.
Initially, when I wrote the service, I only had a GRPC client. Everything worked well until the moment when I added a GRPC server to the same service. After adding it, requests to the GRPC server are successful, but when trying to make a request through the GRPC client, the request simply freezes.

Dependencies i have in pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>9.22.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.devh</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-client-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.devh</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-server-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
            <version>${grpc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
            <version>${grpc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-netty</artifactId>
            <version>${grpc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-testing</artifactId>
            <version>1.61.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>${jpamodelgen.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.0</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                            <version>${jpamodelgen.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:${protobuf.version}:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
                    <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
                    <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${grpc.version}:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</pluginArtifact>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>compile-custom</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Applcation.yaml

```
spring:
  main:
    banner-mode: off
  datasource:
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?prepareThreshold=0
    username: user
    password: postgres
  jpa:
    generate-ddl: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
  flyway:
    enabled: true

server:
  port: 8081

grpc:
  client:
    account-grpc-server:
      address: static://localhost:8080
      enableKeepAlive: true
      keepAliveWithoutCalls: true
      negotiationType: plaintext
  server:
    port: 8082

logging:
  level:
    root: trace
    grpc: trace
```

In logs due request i have

```
2024-02-20T21:39:08.645+06:00 DEBUG 22556 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] io.grpc.ChannelLogger                    : [Channel<1>: (static://localhost:8080)] Exiting idle mode
2024-02-20T21:39:08.651+06:00 DEBUG 22556 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] io.grpc.util.MultiChildLoadBalancer      : Created
2024-02-20T21:39:08.652+06:00 TRACE 22556 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] io.grpc.ChannelLogger                    : [Channel<1>: (static://localhost:8080)] Resolved address: [[[localhost/127.0.0.1:8080]/{}]], config={io.grpc.internal.RetryingNameResolver.RESOLUTION_RESULT_LISTENER_KEY=io.grpc.internal.RetryingNameResolver$ResolutionResultListener@4dd6799c}
2024-02-20T21:39:08.652+06:00 DEBUG 22556 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] io.grpc.ChannelLogger                    : [Channel<1>: (static://localhost:8080)] Address resolved: [[[localhost/127.0.0.1:8080]/{}]]
2024-02-20T21:39:08.658+06:00 DEBUG 22556 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] io.grpc.Context                          : Storage override doesn't exist. Using default

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.grpc.override.ContextStorageOverride
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.Context$LazyStorage.createStorage(Context.java:129) ~[grpc-api-1.59.0.jar:1.59.0]
    at io.grpc.Context$LazyStorage.<clinit>(Context.java:118) ~[grpc-api-1.59.0.jar:1.59.0]
    at io.grpc.Context.storage(Context.java:106) ~[grpc-api-1.59.0.jar:1.59.0]
    at io.grpc.Context.current(Context.java:172) ~[grpc-api-1.59.0.jar:1.59.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.<init>(ClientCallImpl.java:122) ~[grpc-core-1.59.0.jar:1.59.0]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840) ~[na:na]

2024-02-20T21:39:09.280+06:00 DEBUG 22556 --- [nio-8081-Poller] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : timeout completed: keys processed=1; now=1708443549280; nextExpiration=1708443548904; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false
2024-02-20T21:39:09.911+06:00 DEBUG 22556 --- [5)-172.20.10.14] sun.rmi.transport.tcp                    : RMI TCP Connection(5)-172.20.10.14: accepted socket from [172.20.10.14:62195]
```

I try to make requests locally, but i didn't help.

Update:
I add deadline for this request:

```
try {
            return accountServiceBlockingStub.withDeadlineAfter(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                             .setAccountsForMerchant(getAccountBasicRequest(requestId, merchantId, contractFee));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            var message = String.format("Error when getting response from account-service: %s", e.getMessage());
            log.error(message, e);

            throw new AccountServiceResponseException(messageService.getMessage(ACCOUNT_SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE), 400);
        }
```

After passing 5 seconds I received the following logs after the ones I sent earlier.

```
2024-02-21T09:04:51.670+06:00 DEBUG 1976 --- [nio-8099-Poller] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : timeout completed: keys processed=1; now=1708484691669; nextExpiration=1708484691664; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false
2024-02-21T09:04:52.684+06:00 DEBUG 1976 --- [nio-8099-Poller] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : timeout completed: keys processed=1; now=1708484692684; nextExpiration=1708484692669; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false
2024-02-21T09:04:53.699+06:00 DEBUG 1976 --- [nio-8099-Poller] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : timeout completed: keys processed=1; now=1708484693699; nextExpiration=1708484693684; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false
2024-02-21T09:04:54.709+06:00 DEBUG 1976 --- [nio-8099-Poller] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : timeout completed: keys processed=1; now=1708484694709; nextExpiration=1708484694699; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false
2024-02-21T09:04:55.721+06:00 DEBUG 1976 --- [nio-8099-Poller] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : timeout completed: keys processed=1; now=1708484695721; nextExpiration=1708484695709; keyCount=0; hasEvents=false; eval=false
2024-02-21T09:04:55.872+06:00 ERROR 1976 --- [nio-8099-exec-8] k.p.m.service.grpc.AccountService        : Error when getting response from account-service: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: deadline exceeded after 4.794824000s. Name resolution delay 0.000000000 seconds. [closed=[], open=[[buffered_nanos=4802324400, waiting_for_connection]]]

io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: deadline exceeded after 4.794824000s. Name resolution delay 0.000000000 seconds. [closed=[], open=[[buffered_nanos=4802324400, waiting_for_connection]]]
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:268) ~[grpc-stub-1.59.0.jar:1.59.0]
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:249) ~[grpc-stub-1.59.0.jar:1.59.0]
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:167) ~[grpc-stub-1.59.0.jar:1.59.0]
    at kz.paspay.paspayledgerservice.grpc.AccountServiceGrpc$AccountServiceBlockingStub.setAccountsForMerchant(AccountServiceGrpc.java:358) ~[classes/:na]
    at kz.paspay.merchantserviceinner.service.grpc.AccountService.setAccountsForMerchant(AccountService.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
    at kz.paspay.merchantserviceinner.service.MerchantService.createAccounts(MerchantService.java:185) ~[classes/:na]
    at kz.paspay.merchantserviceinner.service.MerchantService.createMerchant(MerchantService.java:69) ~[classes/:na]
    ...

2024-02-21T09:04:55.886+06:00 TRACE 1976 --- [nio-8099-exec-8] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [kz.paspay.merchantserviceinner.service.MerchantService.createMerchant] after exception: AccountServiceResponseException(code=400)
2024-02-21T09:04:55.886+06:00 DEBUG 1976 --- [nio-8099-exec-8] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Initiating transaction rollback
```

Comment: There's not much to go on here. I suggest using `stub.withDeadlineAfter(5, SECONDS).yourRpcMethod(req)` to add a deadline to the client's RPC and then seeing what error you get back. grpc-java adds timing information to the error when the deadline is exceeded.

Comment: Thank you for response :) Do deadline for request as you asked, added new logs to the question. Can you check them please

Comment: Cross-linking: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/10940

Comment: `waiting_for_connection`. Something is taking connection establishment a long time. If you waited long enough (like 60s or more, although it varies depending on the DNS results) the RPC would have failed without the deadline. I'd check the server IP addresses are correct in DNS and that there's no misconfigured firewall on the client and server.

Comment: I tried to up both services to make that request locally, the result is the same

Comment: Are you running within containers?

Comment: Nope. without them

Comment: Just wanted to confirm that when you said locally, you meant using 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Yes, I specified both localhost and 127.0.0.1 as the host for the request.